# How to hide page numbers for some pages in the Word document using field code?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, page-numbers

I want to skip page numbers for some pages in the Word document (in my case 4, for example pages 10,12,14,17). With that I mean that page numbers for these pages are not shown, but page numbers on other pages remain same. I know that just for page 10, this can be done (as can be deduced from [here](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/how_to_skip_page_numbers_for_some_pages_in_the_word_document.html)) by inserting the following formula in the footer:

`{IF {PAGE} <> "10" "{page}"}`

However, I don't know how to do that for multiple page numbers.

I'm using Word 2016.

Comment: Please copy&paste text to your question **as text** instead of showing a screenshot. Please [edit] your question and add more details: What do you mean with "skip page numbers" ? Omit the page number from the footer for certain numbers? Change the numbering, e.g. page 11 should follow page 9 etc? How many page numbers do you want to suppress?

Comment: I want to suppress 4 page numbers (same amount as in the mentioned example above).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to answer requests for clarification, don't use comments to add information. I'm not a MS Word specialist. Maybe the formula can contain nested conditions, e.g. `{IF {PAGE} <> "10" {IF {PAGE} <> "12" {IF {PAGE} <> "14" {IF {PAGE} <> "17" "{page}"}}}}`? Or try `AND`operations `{ IF { = AND ( AND ( { COMPARE {PAGE} <> "10" }, { COMPARE {PAGE} <> "12" } ), AND ( { COMPARE {PAGE} <> "14" }, { COMPARE {PAGE} <> "17" } ) ) } = 1 "{PAGE}"}`. Everything is untested. The 2nd suggestion is based on the examples in https://bettersolutions.com/word/fields/if-field.htm

Comment: I just tried both of them and the upper suggestion works as desired.

Comment: I will make this to an answer, that you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a small amount of page numbers to check you can explicitly write all conditions.

You can try nested conditions like this

```
{IF {PAGE} <> "10" {IF {PAGE} <> "12" {IF {PAGE} <> "14" {IF {PAGE} <> "17" "{page}"}}}}
```

It might also be possible to use `AND` operations/functions to construct a combined condition as shown in the examples on this page https://bettersolutions.com/word/fields/if-field.htm